# Limited truck limitations on Here android-sdk?

Tags: android, here-api

Building a truck-aware navigation app with Here Maps Android SDK, I notice what I believe are limitations I'd like to solve, work around or at least have explained:

- Turning on truck options in routing creates a different route, but it still goes through residential no-truck streets
- Displaying truck limitations on the map show a very small subset of truck limitations known to Here.

I confirmed the truck/no-truck segments are known to Here using [Here Map Creator](https://mapcreator.here.com)

Can my app have only downloaded/cached incomplete street attributes? All the streets are there though.

Example: From 45.573640, -73.59549 to 45.5323101, -73.7170627. The last 5km of the route to destination is the significant part here.

My application in truck mode shows this (no truck circled red):
[image: Truck-aware routing in my app]

Same map zoomed out to show how few truck restrictions are displayed:
[image]

Map creator shows the no-truck segment. Many segments in same area are no-truck:
[image]

Comment: Please provide some examples to prove your case 1 and 2 so that we can investigate on it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a possible explanation to the use of no-truck streets in my example, though I'm not sure it is right.

Here is a shot of the [city issued map of no truck zones](https://services.montreal.ca/camionnage/) with the route highlighted by me:
[image]

It turns out there is no way to get there without using no-truck streets. I haven't checked all the street entries in MapCreator but many are designated as no truck.

Should the routing work like that, should it have failed? This still does not answer the very few no-truck indications on the map?